# how to receive the value

Tags: php, jquery

the php file:

```
if (!isset($servers[$ext])){
    die('no match data!');
}
return $output;
```

the html file:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"get",
    url:"/tests/api/?u="+u,
    dataType:"json",
    data:"",
    success:function result(data){
        $("#show").html(data);
        $("#show").show();


    }
});
```

when happens `no match data!'`. the html file can't output `no match data!` tips, how to output it, thank you.

there is a response (no match data!)in the firebug console.but the html file can't output it.now, i want to the html file can output the no match data! tips how should i do

Comment: I'm not sure using die here is useful?  Die is to be used for catestrophic failures such as being unable to contact a db

Comment: Is the snippet you provided the only PHP in the api file. Are you using some kind of framework to power your API? Unless the snippet you provided is within a function, the return does nothing.

Comment: yeah, the code is in an api file.and i used the zend framework

Comment: @zhuanzhou I figured this much. I was fairly certain you weren't returning for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If you die you won't reach the return. @PhpMyCoder

```
   if (!isset($servers[$ext])){
       $output="no match data!";
    }
    return(json_encode($output));
```

Comment: @Linus Kleen why?? i think the $output was goin empty || null

Comment: I thought that dead things can`t talk.

Comment: i am sorry, it doesn't work, there is a response (no match data!)in the firebug console.but the html file can't output it.

Comment: You can't tell the script to `die()` and then expect it to return data *afterwards*.

Comment: Your script ends its execution when it reaches the die.

Comment: i get it edited the answer... tnx for pointing/poking me in the right direction @Linus Kleen  Bakudan PhpMyCoder

Comment: @Linus Kleen i just mentioned that i made the edited after reading his comment didnt and edited the answer

Comment: @3nigma The echo should be a return. As zhuanzhou stated in the comments above, he is using zend as a framework for his API. The zend framework calls a function and the code the OP posted was from inside the function that would be called. I would think echoing the string would work, but zend may start an output buffer to prevent functions from echoing data. At least, this is what I gather.

Answer (score 2):

why using the "die" function while you just want to echo something as an answer from the server?
Remember that when you are using an ajax request, there is not much this request will be able to grab as a response. You'll be able to catch any HTTP response code, its associated text + any text answer.

Simply echo something, json_encode them if you want to have more flexibility in handling multiple values in javascript and that'll do!

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax request is expecting json. In jQuery 1.4 malform json will be rejected.

If you want to return html, set

```
dataType:"html",
```

Or set your die statement to return json.

Comment: @zhuanzhou  set `$output="no match";` and `echo(json_encode($output));`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!isset($servers[$ext])){
    return "no match data!";
}
```

Comment: If you die you won't reach the return.

Comment: ...aaand `return` wont output anything by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

The PHP file:

```
if (!isset($servers[$ext])){
    $output = 'no match data!';
}
// for good measure, tell the client json is coming back.
header('Content-type: application/json');

echo(json_encode($output));

return;
```

The JavaScript remains the same.